# Reduce 12 digit unique code to 10 digit

Tags: unique, digit, reduction

i have a problem where we need to generate Unique codes for few million rows in a table that has several other data cases. 
For ex - table has data for case A, B, C - each having million rows.

Need to generate uniques only for data in case A.

Issue is that - we have a 12 digit unique number (all integers - those will not repeat within A, but can repeat across A & B & C... say like customerIDs ), but the space for storing unique code (which can be alphanumeric) is just 10 :) .

Tried to work out a solution where we can take ascii to reduce a length. For ex - if 65 appears in the 12 digit number, we will read it as "A"....& so on..this reduces 1 digit..but there is no guarantee that 65 will appear...

Any clues will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered converting the number to its hexadecimal representation?

Comment: Thanks Jeroen..I tried doing it, but it is giving me "invalid number" error. The field is actually stored as Character, so I need to convert it to number first (that is also giving same error). using the following - to_number(substr(<field>,10,5),'XXXXXX') - tried using cast but getting same error

Comment: thanks Joren, after we did the error handling, it worked well